# javaScript Validar con fecha de nacimiento si es mayor de edad

Tags: javascript, html, formularios, funciones, alert

Validar  fecha de nacimiento, permitiendo sólo cargar Currículums de una persona mayor
de edad, notificando al usuario en caso de no cumplir dicha condición y no permitir Enviar
los datos.

con este label

```
<label>Fecha nacimiento:</label><input type='Date' value='' id="fechanaci" required ></div>
```

y este codigo para tomar el valor del label

```
<form onsubmit = "return validaedad(document.getElementById('fechanaci').value)">
```

hice esta funcion en js

```
function validaedad (fecha_naci) {
    
    alert (fecha_naci);
    var valores = fecha_naci.split ("-");
    var dia_naci = valores [2];
    var mes_naci = valores [1];
    var anio_naci = valores [0];
    
    
    var fecha_act = new Date();
    var dia_act = fecha_act.getDate();
    var mes_act = fecha_act.getMonth() + 1;
    var anio_act = fecha_act.getFullYear();
```

me falta codigo para que muestre si es menor de edad no deje enviar el mensaje. como deberia hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

te dejo un código que te permite calcular la edad de una persona segun la fecha de nacimiento, similar a lo que estas tratando de hacer.

```js
function calcularEdad(fecha_nacimiento) {
    var hoy = new Date();
    var cumpleanos = new Date(fecha_nacimiento);
    var edad = hoy.getFullYear() - cumpleanos.getFullYear();
    var m = hoy.getMonth() - cumpleanos.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && hoy.getDate() < cumpleanos.getDate())) {
        edad--;
    }
    return edad;
}

var edad = calcularEdad("2000/08/10");
if(edad >= 18){
    alert("Eres mayor de edad :D ");
}else{
    alert("Eres menor de edad :( ");
}
```

En tu código puedes reemplazar la función utilizada por la nueva, ejemplo:

```
<form onsubmit = "return calcularEdad(document.getElementById('fechanaci').value)">
```

El formato de la fecha debe ser: año/mes/dia.

Saludos